# Вызывать метод инстанса через аксессор плохая практика?

Tags: javascript, ооп, typescript, шаблоны-проектирования, solid

В настоящее время я изучаю принципы ООП и SOLID.

В этом примере я получаю данные с сервера и обрабатываю их с помощью композиции.

Насколько я понимаю, вызов методов через аксессор — неправильный подход.

```
columns.inputFieldsColumn.recalculateInputFields('test1');
columns.amountColumn.removeItem('test2');
```

Как переписать правильно этот код?

```
class InputFieldsColumn {
    constructor(fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    recalculateInputFields(machineName) {
        this.fields = this.fields.map(i => i.machineName === machineName ? i.value + 1 : i);
    }

    addItem(item) {
        this.fields = this.fields.push(item);
    }
}

class AmountColumn {
    constructor(fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    recalculateAmount(machineName) {
        this.fields = this.fields.map(i => i.machineName === machineName ? i.value + 23 : i);
    }

    removeItem(machineName) {
        this.fields = this.fields.filter(item => item.machineName !== machineName);
    }
}


class Init {
    constructor(columns) {
        this._inputFieldsColumn = new InputFieldsColumn(columns.inputFieldsColumn);
        this._amountColumn = new AmountColumn(columns.amountColumn);
    }

    get inputFieldsColumn() {
        return this._inputFieldsColumn;
    }

    get amountColumn() {
        return this._amountColumn;
    }
}

const columns = new Init({ inputFieldsColumn: [{ value: 15, machineName: 'test1' }], amountColumn: [{ value: 24, machineName: 'test2' }] });

columns.inputFieldsColumn.recalculateInputFields('test1');
columns.amountColumn.recalculateAmount('test2');
columns.amountColumn.removeItem('test2');
```

Comment: *"Насколько я понимаю, вызов методов через аксессор — неправильный подход."* --- почему? Как раз наоборот, вполне себе правильно. Неправильно напрямую обращаться к `_inputFieldsColumn ` и `_amountColumn` ... И то, если доступ только на чтение был бы - то можно было бы и напрямую

Comment: @АлексейШиманский аксессор "get" нужен только для чтения, разве нет? А тут я неявно мутирую объект. Возможно я ошибаюсь)

Comment: getter нужен для невозможности доступа к свойствам напрямую + для возможности контролировать данные (в геттере может быть доп. логика). Дальше просто у объекта вызывается метод. Проблемы тут не вижу..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понял, благодарю за разъяснение